# Why identified by the name Og?

Tags: names, midrash, parashat-lech-lecha, abraham

Although the Midrash Bereshis Rabbah [(42:8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.42.8?lang=bi) records the story behind the origin of Og's name:

> וַיָּבֹא הַפָּלִיט (בראשית יד, יג), רֵישׁ לָקִישׁ בְּשֵׁם בַּר
>   קַפָּרָא הוּא עוֹג הוּא פָּלִיט, וְלָמָּה נִקְרָא שְׁמוֹ עוֹג שֶׁבָּא
>   וּמָצָא אֶת אַבְרָם יוֹשֵׁב וְעוֹסֵק בְּמִצְוַת עוּגוֹת

Reish Lakish understands Og's name stems from finding Avraham working in mitzvah of matza 'cakes'. However, why does that scene inspire the Torah to call Og 'cake' forever? Is there an assumed zechus Og had for seeing Avraham make matza?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Munkatcher Rebbe is quoted as asking this question [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=4716#p=65&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=%u05E0%u05E7%u05E8%u05D0%20%u05E9%u05DE%u05D5%20%u05E2%u05D5%u05D2). He answers that the Arizal is quoted as having said that at the time of matzah baking one should exert oneself and sweat and this will atone for the husks of needlessly wasting seed. By being in the vicinity of Avraham's matzah bake, Og merited to shed the seed wasting husks.

This spiritual event is so significant, that Og is forever named after these cakes.

Comment: See also [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=51144#p=30&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=%u05E0%u05E7%u05E8%u05D0%20%u05E9%u05DE%u05D5%20%u05E2%u05D5%u05D2) and [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=20577#p=149&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=%u05E0%u05E7%u05E8%u05D0%20%u05E9%u05DE%u05D5%20%u05E2%u05D5%u05D2).

Comment: Great find - thank you! I saw Rav Yitzchak Zilberstein bring a similar answer but wasn't sure how to understand it. Would you please explain how being in the vicinity of a big mitzvah taking place is a zechus?

Comment: I assume it is a Hassidic belief. I don't know more about it.

Comment: It's a Tosfos belief

Comment: @sam I don't understand, Tosfot doesn't say any of this

Comment: זה עוג שפלט מדור המבול. הכי נמי נפלט סיחון מדור המבול כיון דאחי הוו אלא דהך הפליט קים ליה דהוא עוג ולא סיחון מהאי טעמא גופיה כיון דדחיל ליה משה ועוד אמר (בפרק רבי אליעזר) (דף לד) שעוג מצאו לאברהם אבינו שהיה עומד בגרנות לתקן עוגות לפסח ועל שם זה נקרא עוג ומייתי ליה משום דמחזי כלישנא בישא דאמר במדרש עוג אמר בלבו אלך ואומר לאברהם וילחם וימות ואשא שרה אשתו אפילו הכי היה ירא משה שמא תעמוד לו זכות אברהם:

Comment: Tosfos brings the Pirkei which explains how Og got his nickname ,his true name was פליט

Comment: @sam but that's not what's in this answer. The Pirkei was quoted in the question already